# Bitbake: pass string with spaces to meson config

Tags: yocto, bitbake, meson-build

With meson, it is possible to pass a string with spaces during configuration, e.g. below usage cases are all valid:

```
meson -Dfoo="bar1 bar2" ...
meson "-Dfoo=bar1 bar2" ...
meson -Dfoo='bar1 bar2' ...
meson '-Dfoo=bar1 bar2' ...
```

When building a recipe with Bitbake, `EXTRA_OEMESON` is used to pass configuration parameters to meson. 
I tried below but they all failed:

Surround the string with `""` or `''`

```
EXTRA_OEMESON = " -Dfoo=\"bar1 bar2\" "
# Results in
#meson: error: unrecognized arguments: bar2"
```

Surround the whole `-Dxxx` with `""` or `''`:

```
EXTRA_OEMESON = " \"-Dfoo=bar1 bar2\" "
# Results in
# meson: error: unrecognized arguments: "-Dfoo=bar1 bar2"
```

So the question is, how to pass such a string with space to meson in bitbake?

Comment: Have you tried two layers of quotation instead of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just surrounding the value with quotes should work:

```
EXTRA_OEMESON = "-Dfoo='bar1 bar2'"
```